# How to check if shared memory exists?

Tags: python, windows, shared-memory

I need to access to a windows shared memory using Python.

I saw at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26171682) post that command,

```
shm = mmap.mmap(0, 512, "Local\\Test")
```

However as I saw it does attached to an existing shared memory but also create  a new one if it not exists. 
How can I force to attach the shared memory if it exists but not to create one?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html#mmap.mmap) it sounds like you may be able change the `512` to `0` in the call which will cause an exception to be raised if it doesn't already exist (because a non-existent file would be considered "empty").

Comment: @martineau, but then opening an existing mapping would also fail as an invalid parameter. mmap doesn't support opening exclusive.

Comment: The underlying WINAPI `CreateFileMappingW` call succeeds if it already exists, with the last error set to `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, but mmap doesn't have a need to check for this. More simply, we can use ctypes to call `OpenFileMappingW`, which only succeeds if the mapping already exists.

Comment: FYI, mapping share memory via the paging file should use -1 as the file descriptor, not 0. Using 0 is technically allowed in Windows but not advised because it doesn't work in POSIX. It's supported in Windows for the sake of compatibility with the old, mistaken implementation.

Comment: Consider using [SharedMemory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html). It seems to be a wrapper around `mmap` which does what you need, compare the `create` parameter in `class multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=None, create=False, size=0)`. Also checkout out https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py.